# Typedef (anonymous) struct array of size 1

Tags: c++, c, gmp

So recently I've been poking around in the internals of GMP for a project I'm working on, and I've encountered a construct that makes very little sense to me: (taken from the header for version 6.2.1)

```cpp
/* For reference, note that the name __mpz_struct gets into C++ mangled
   function names, which means although the "__" suggests an internal, we
   must leave this name for binary compatibility.  */
typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;        /* Number of *limbs* allocated and pointed
                   to by the _mp_d field.  */
  int _mp_size;         /* abs(_mp_size) is the number of limbs the
                   last field points to.  If _mp_size is
                   negative this is a negative number.  */
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;     /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;

#endif /* __GNU_MP__ */


typedef __mpz_struct MP_INT;    /* gmp 1 source compatibility */
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

On the final line here, we typedef `mpz_t` to be an array of size 1 containing `__mpz_struct`s. This is very strange to me, and I've never seen a construction like this before. I understand that this results in `mpz_t` effectively being a pointer to an `__mpz_struct`, but is this equivalent or not to

```
typedef __mpz_struct* mpz_t;
```

Could somebody explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Array declarations are only converted to pointers in function parameter lists. Not in typedef.

Comment: "*is this equivalent or not*". It's not equivalent. The former is an array which can decay to a pointer. Such a pointer is always a valid address. The latter is just a pointer and is invalid until it is set to point to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];`, you can declare an actual `mpz_t` object with `mpz_t foo;`. This will reserve memory for an `mpz_t`.

In contrast, if the type were `typedef __mpz_struct *mpz_t;`, then `mpz_t foo;` would only give you a pointer. There would be no space for an `mpz_t`. You would have to allocate it, and you would have to free it later. So more code is required, and it would be a nuisance.

At the same time, when an `mpz_t` is passed to a function, only its address is passed, due to the automatic conversion of arrays to pointers. This allows writing `mpz_add(z, x, y);`, which is less cluttered than `mpz_add(&z, &x, &y);`. There may be arguments among programmers about whether it is bug-prone to use a type definition that effectively results in a reference to an object being passed to a function when the code nominally looks like just a value is passed, but this style may be more suitable for the type of programming done with GMP.

Answer (score 2):

With that `typedef`, a variable declaration like

```
mpz_t foo;
```

is equivalent to

```
__mpz_struct foo[1];
```

This will only be converted to

```
__mpz_struct *foo;
```

if the declaration is in a function parameter list. Otherwise, it's a ordinary array declaration.